# Asus Zenbook UX443FN with Nvidia MX150 driver in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: nvidia

kernel:

```
5.4.45-050445-generic
```

ubuntu version :

```
hendranata@pc:~$ uname -a
Linux pc 5.4.45-050445-generic #202006070831 SMP Sun Jun 7 12:35:05 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

i have perform install nvidia driver for my laptop ux433fn:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

the result is:

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-460-server : Depends: libnvidia-gl-460-server (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libnvidia-encode-460-server (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-460-server (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-460-server (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Recommends: libnvidia-decode-460-server:i386 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.2)
                            Recommends: libnvidia-encode-460-server:i386 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.2)
                            Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-460-server:i386 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.2)
                            Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-460-server:i386 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.2)
                            Recommends: libnvidia-gl-460-server:i386 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.2)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

i have perform "sudo apt-get install -f" but the issue still same..

```
hendranata@pc:~$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

nvidia X also show only prime mode:

[image]

when i try to choose driver-460-server (proprietary, tested) and click apply changes.. it revert back to original.. no idea why. seems i cant install driver-460

[image]

multiple time try and error + reboot, it always show that my laptop uses Intel GPU

[image]

any idea which version driver that compatible with my laptop nvidia mx150 ?

Comment: The only way it will show the Intel driver is if you have a motherboard chip set using that driver. How many video connections are on the machine.

Comment: Linux pc 5.4.45-050445-generic #202006070831 SMP Sun Jun 7 12:35:05 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: There is something *fishy* (not right) with your pastes, a fully updated *bionic* (18.04) system will report itself as 18.04.5, but yours states 18.04.2.  A 18.04.2 system running HWE will be using the 4.18 kernel but you are showing the 5.4 kernel?? so something doesn't add up with your pastes.... Have you edited them? and are actually running something different? (but are trying to pretend it's Ubuntu when it's not, for if those are legit pastes, something is corrupted in your system as results are inconsistent!).  I'd check your system's security status...

Comment: i upgrade the kernel and now running under kernel 5.4.45-050445-generic